# Nested foreach with huge data causes Out of memory exeption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, out-of-memory

I am dealing with data returned by a machine. The machine normally used in big farms and it will collect data in each points in different depth and using different devices.

Each farm may contain 70-100 fields and each field contains around 10 Million data

Here i need to process each data and apply some calculations based on client requirements.

I need to iterate through Farms first then fields under farm then devices used for each farm then records for each device  based on depth.
So finally I hope i am doing around 1 billion iterations.
My code looks like below

```
    public async void MigrateData()
        {
            masterData = await CatalogService.ExportMasterData(AppDataModel.Catalog, this.UserId);

            foreach (var fieldItem in masterData.Fields)
            {
                var fieldReferenceId = fieldItem.ReferenceId;

                dynamic loggedData = AppDataModel.Documents.LoggedData.Where(data => data.FieldId == fieldReferenceId);
                dynamic fieldDbMappingData = fieldItem;

                foreach (var data in loggedData)
                {
                    yieldMaster.OperationalLogModalResponse = await YieldDataMigrationService.AddOperationalLogs("loggedDataDescription");
                    yieldMaster.OperationalLogDataModelResponse = await YieldDataMigrationService.AddOperationalLogData(fieldDbMappingData, yieldMaster.OperationalLogModalResponse);

                    FetchContentData(data);

                }

            }

        }
 private async void FetchContentData(LoggedData data)
        {

            foreach (var opdata in data.OperationData)
            {
               var filteredList = AggregateDataBasedOnFilter(opdata);

                int count = filteredList.Count;
                totalRecordCount += count;
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i = i + 1000)
                {
                    var response = await YieldDataMigrationService.AddYiledData(filteredList.GetRange(i, i + 1000 >= count ? count - i : 1000));

                }
            }
            //Filter data based on timestamp values , get the first data in 5 seconds interval

            System.GC.Collect();
        } 

 private dynamic AggregateDataBasedOnFilter(OperationData opdata)
        {
            List<dynamic> listSpacialRecords = new List<dynamic>();
            IEnumerable<SpatialRecord> spacialRecords = opdata.GetSpatialRecords();
            spacialRecords = GetAggregateBasedOnTimeStamb(spacialRecords);
            Nullable<Guid> productid;
            for (int depth = 0; depth <= opdata.MaxDepth; depth++)
            {
                IEnumerable<DeviceElementUse> deviceElementUses = opdata.GetDeviceElementUses(depth);
                StevProduct productDbMappingData = masterData.Products.Where(product => product.ReferenceId == opdata.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (productDbMappingData == null)
                {
                    productid = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    productid = productDbMappingData.Id;
                }
                foreach (var deviceElement in deviceElementUses)
                {

                    List<dynamic> dvList = new List<dynamic>();
                    IEnumerable<WorkingData> workingData = deviceElement.GetWorkingDatas();

                    //foreach (var spacerecord in spacialRecords)
                    Parallel.ForEach(spacialRecords, (spacerecord) =>
                   {
                       List<MeterValue> dat = new List<MeterValue>();
                       var latitude = ((AgGateway.ADAPT.ApplicationDataModel.Shapes.Point)spacerecord.Geometry).Y;
                       var longitude = ((AgGateway.ADAPT.ApplicationDataModel.Shapes.Point)spacerecord.Geometry).X;
                       var timeStamp = spacerecord.Timestamp;
                       //Parallel.ForEach(workingData, (wdItem) =>
                       foreach (var wdItem in workingData)
                       {
                           RepresentationValue spaceMeteredValue = spacerecord.GetMeterValue(wdItem);
                           if (spaceMeteredValue != null && wdItem.Representation != null)
                           {
                               //row[wdItem.Representation.Code] = meteredValue.Value.Value;
                               var objMeterValue = new MeterValue();
                               objMeterValue.key = wdItem.Representation.Code;
                               objMeterValue.value = spaceMeteredValue.Designator != null ? Convert.ToString(spaceMeteredValue.Designator) : "";
                               dat.Add(objMeterValue);
                           }
                       }
                       var newSpacialvalue = new
                       {
                           operationLogDataId = yieldMaster.OperationalLogDataModelResponse.Id,
                           order = deviceElement.Order,
                           totalDistanceTravelled = deviceElement.TotalDistanceTravelled,
                           totalElapsedTime = deviceElement.TotalElapsedTime,
                           uploadedOn = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                           collectedOn = timeStamp.ToUniversalTime(),
                           cropId = "8296e610-c055-11e7-851e-ad7650a5f99c",
                           productId = productid,
                           latitude = latitude,
                           longitude = longitude,
                           deviceConfigurationId = deviceElement.DeviceConfigurationId,
                           operationDataId = deviceElement.OperationDataId,
                           spatialRecords = dat,
                           depth = depth,
                           timeStamp = timeStamp,
                           totaldata = totalRecordCount
                       };
                       lock (listSpacialRecords)
                       {
                           listSpacialRecords.Add(newSpacialvalue);
                       }

                   });


                }
            }

            listSpacialRecords = listSpacialRecords
                  .Skip(1)
                  .Aggregate(
                      listSpacialRecords.Take(1).ToList(),
                      (a, x) =>
                      {
                          if (x.timeStamp.Subtract(a.Last().timeStamp).TotalSeconds >= 10.0)
                          {
                              a.Add(x);
                          }
                          return a;
                      });
            GC.Collect();
            return listSpacialRecords;

        }
```

My real scenario is more complex than this. It has lot of `foreach` and calculations. The overall process is running for more than 30 min. But in between I am getting out of memory 
exception. No idea about how to deal with this much huge data.

Anyone have any better approach than nested foreach ?? Or any solution for avoiding out of memory ??

Note : I have moved each look in separate functions but still its showing out of memory error. Also I have a local list which deals with data calculated by the logic section. Local list  It is not a global object

Comment: Skip Take and process batches?

Comment: Why are you making **three** calls to `foreach (var fields in FieldData)`?

Comment: @stuartd sorry it was a typo. Edited

Comment: @Saruman What you mean by skip take and process batches? I didnt get you

Comment: @Saruman Are you taking about process some data from another method ??

Comment: Depending on the environemnt, its it possible take chucks of data from the farms and not the whole set

Comment: @Saruman It is not possible because we are getting this data from an external function call and that function is defined in third party dll. So they are giving the entire data as a collection.

Comment: OutOfMemory is not occurring because you are iterating over a large set but because you might be saving that data in temporary variables which might not be garbage cleared fast enough. I think you should do some explicit garbage collection after some set number of checks

Comment: @puneet yes i have some local savings

Comment: @puneet but that local variable is not a global one, is it for a field so for a field one local list and i am manually calling GC.Collect() in end of loop

Comment: are you calling GC.Collect after ContentData loop or after the entire thing, I did not get the field part you mentioned

Comment: Farms will have fields or in simple a farm is a collection fields. GC.Collect after ContentData  loop

Comment: There really isn't enough information here. The most suspect part is "Adding data to local list" but we can't see how the lifetime of that list is managed. You shouln't need `GC.Collect()` .

Comment: @HenkHolterman i will add more data

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added the real code instead of sample code , Please have a look on that

Comment: And now there is way too much code... It's unlikely that somebody will have a general answer for you, you will have to investigate (Memory Profiler) and/or analyze your code.

Answer (score 0):

As Puneet pointed out in comments "OutOfMemory is not occurring because you are iterating over a large set but because you might be saving that data in temporary variables which might not be garbage cleared fast enough. I think you should do some explicit garbage collection after some set number of checks"

Would be better if you dispose elements manually when not needed.

```
{object}.Dispose();
```

Or put garbage collections statements at end of all loops.

```
GC.Collect();
```

Also You can use Parallel.Foreach for better performance if your operation are not serial/cumul operations.

Comment: I have GC.Collect(); but still issue is there

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV then you will need to manually dispose objects/caching that you made as long as they are not needed.